# Are "will you be around" and "will you be present" the same?

Tags: phrase-usage

Consider these expressions:

> We are organizing a cultural event X on tuesday at place Y, will you guys be around?
>
> I am thinking of coming to your place this weekend, will you be around?

1. Is the use of "will you be around" correct here?
2. Are the meanings of "will you be around" and "will you be present" the same in this context?

Answer (score 6):

*Will you be around?* means, in this context, ‘Will you be available?' *Will you be present?* means ‘Will you actually be there?’